# Tomcat Servlet Logger not printing everything

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, servlets

I have a simple java HTTP Servlet which receives XML messages, parses them and then saves to a database. Everything works fine; the data is saved correctly to the database, but the logging seems to be not working 100% when there are multiple requests being sent to the servlet rapidly.

My logging is just simple print out in the doPost method; a timestamp and a unique header-id for every request, so that I can grep by the header-id from logs.

Any ideas why would the logging not print out everything, while the servlet is handling the requests concurrently.

My questions are:

**Is there a buffer in Tomcats default logging system that can't handle rapidly coming requests?**
Because even the requests that dont leave a trace in logs do get saved to the database with right information. I fired about 400 requests in one second and a few got left out from the logs (I used grep to search).

**Should I use Log4J?**

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet { 

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        String headerID = request.getHeader("HeaderID");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ServletInputStream inputstream = request.getInputStream();
        
       //Printing out a timestamp and header-id as soon as doPost gets called (ie. by Postman)
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'['dd.MM.yyyy '||' HH:mm:ss.SSS']'");
        System.out.println("TIMESTAMP :: " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + " HEADER-ID :: " + headerID);
        try {
            //
            // Here is some logic for checking if the received XML is valid
            //
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
            System.out.println(
                    "ERROR " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      // If XML is valid, then proceed to parse it to an object and save to database

      new SaveXML(inputstream, response, headerID).run();

}
```

Comment: Is the problem that some log info from individual requests are missing or is the problem that whole requests have their log info completely gone? For example, the logs show request info for request 1, 2, skip 3, then show info for 4?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil individual requests are missing. One request = one line of log. But this should be impossible because because I'm printing TIMESTAMP asap when doPost is called.

Comment: Are you sure they are missing and not just out of order?

Comment: Yes. If I try to grep the log-file with a unique ID that comes with every request(in header), they do not exist, but at the same time I can find them from the database.

Comment: The buffering for logging is not suppose to be enabled by default. You can check your server.xml file in the conf directory to see if its been set to true or not. You could also check the access logs and confirm theres 1 line for each request you've sent  just to further confirm all requests are getting through.

Comment: See my last comment. Theres a number of ways to configuring logging so probably best to find the logging section of this link that applies to your version of tomcat https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html where that link is for Tomcat 7. With regard to log4j, I dont think that will solve your issue. Log4j just gives you more control over what gets logged by allowing you add "log levels" to your code. Its not going to have higher throughput than the raw Tomcat logger.